# Can I flag my own post for moderators attention , if the voting on that post seems suspicious?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, flags

Last day, I posted an answer to a question and was accepted by the user as it solved the issue. Before that, I agree that it was not such a difficult question, but somehow the user was not able to get the required result through the commonly used methods, so I just asked to try an alternative and as I guessed it worked and the user's issue was solved.
But now I see that the post has received 2 upvotes and at the same time **2 downvotes** too. I'm not at all frustrated with the downvotes but I feel it so  bad because the downvotes has been cast even without leaving a single comment and is totally anonymous.
So my question is, If i flag my own post for moderator attention  as shown below
[image]

and write my reason in this textfield, will that make any change? OR will it affect me adversely as I flag my own post? Please contribute your suggestions so that I can proceed with them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Please don't.**

Moderators can't see who downvoted your answer, we can only see suspicious voting *patterns*; for a pattern to emerge, a few more data points than a couple of downvotes are necessary. And if a few more downvotes appear, then they will *most probably* be reversed by [an automated process that runs daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), so flagging for moderation attention would be pointless anyway.

People are encouraged to post comments explaining their downvotes, but aren't required to do so. If it's just the couple of downvotes, ignore them and move on.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you could flag your answer for mod attention, but what do you want to achieve? Are you looking to have the down votes reversed? If so that isn't going to happen.

Two down votes is nothing (although it does hurt if you don't have much rep to begin with). There is also absolutely no requirement for anyone to leave a comment about why they down voted. Answers are not expected to lead to long convoluted discussions, nor are they supposed to be iterative, so answers that don't address the immediate problem can be considered wrong or inaccurate thus accumulating down votes.

So depending on what you are wanting to achieve, flagging this for mod attention probably won't bring you the outcome you want.